# Swig unable to convert byte objectof python3 to std::string

Tags: c++, python-3.5, swig

I am trying to interface python3 with C++ using SWIG and it keeps throwing the following error

```
>> ipc.sendMessage(q, b'qwe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: in method 'sendMessage', argument 2 of type 'std::string'**
```

Below are the attached files:

**ipc.i file**

```
%module ipc

%begin %{
    #define SWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR
    #include "ipc.h"    
%}

%include std_string.i
%include stl.i
%include "ipc.h"
```

**ipc.h file**

```
#include<string>

extern int createQueue();
extern bool sendMessage(int, std::string);
extern std::string receiveMessage(int);
extern bool removeQueue(int);
```

**Command used to build**

```
>> swig -c++ -python ipc.i
>> g++ -fpic -c ipc.h ipc_wrap.cxx ipc.cpp -I/usr/include/python3.5
>> gcc -shared ipc_wrap.o ipc.o -o _ipc.so -lstdc++
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce ([files and log](https://hastebin.com/raw/exazamafay)).  Also your file `ipc.h` is missing header guards and the compiler invocation is wrong (you must not name header files as translation units).

Comment: I re-ran the code snippet mentioned in the link added by you. I am still stuck at the exact same place. Getting the same old error. Kernel Version - 4.13.0-39-generic, C++ standard 11 and python version 3.5.2. Not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because a reproducible example wasn't given.

Comment: Is it possible to mention the SWIG version used by you ?

Comment: Either 3.0.10 or 3.0.12.  I don't remember which machine I tested it on but I can check later.

Comment: I just checked.  It was 3.0.10 on Debian Stretch.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was with SWIG 3.0.8 and got resolved once I updated to 3.0.10

Comment: Awesome, I'll post this as a community wiki answer so you can accept it and remove the question from the unanswered queue.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with SWIG 3.0.8 and got resolved once it was updated to 3.0.10.